# Subdivided random area

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1]      
    \path
    coordinate (aux0) at (1,1.5)
    coordinate (aux1) at (1.7,3.5)
    coordinate (aux2) at (8,3.5)
    coordinate (aux3) at (7,6)
    coordinate (aux4) at (4,1.1)
    coordinate (aux5) at (7,1.3)
    coordinate (aux6) at (2,5.7)
    coordinate (aux7) at (5,5.1)
    coordinate (esp1) at (0.2,2.5)
    coordinate (esp2) at (1.5,1.5)
    coordinate (esp3) at (3,0.9)
    coordinate (esp4) at (5.5,1.4)
    coordinate (esp5) at (6,0.5)
    coordinate (esp6) at (6.75,2)
    coordinate (esp7) at (7.7,3)
    coordinate (esp8) at (5.5,4.5)
    coordinate (esp9) at (3.8,4.8)
    coordinate (esp10) at (1.5,4)
    ;
    \draw[line width=0.8pt]
    (esp1) to[out=-90,in=170]
    (esp2) to[out=-10,in=170]
    (esp3) to[out=-10,in=180]
    (esp4) to[out=0,in=180]
    (esp5) to[out=10,in=-150]
    (esp6) to[out=20,in=-90]
    (esp7) to[out=90,in=-60]
    (esp8) to[out=120,in=0]
    (esp9) to[out=180,in=0]
    (esp10) to[out=180,in=90]
    cycle;    
    \clip
    (esp1) to[out=-90,in=170]
    (esp2) to[out=-10,in=170]
    (esp3) to[out=-10,in=180]
    (esp4) to[out=0,in=180]
    (esp5) to[out=10,in=-150]
    (esp6) to[out=20,in=-90]
    (esp7) to[out=90,in=-60]
    (esp8) to[out=120,in=0]
    (esp9) to[out=180,in=0]
    (esp10) to[out=180,in=90]
    cycle;    

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: *enter image description here*]

> strong text

I have a random region (I already know how to build in TIKZ), I need to divide that same region into rectangles (they don't need to be all the same size), and only one of these rectangles needs to apply hatching. Any ideas where to start?
**

Answer (score 1):

You already provided a very good starting point. Here is one out of many possible ways to go. You can use `decorations.markings` to define coordinates along the contour. They can be used to draw the (clipped) rectangles. Uncomment

```
[label=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}]
```

to see which mark sits where.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,patterns} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1]      
    \path
    coordinate (aux0) at (1,1.5)
    coordinate (aux1) at (1.7,3.5)
    coordinate (aux2) at (8,3.5)
    coordinate (aux3) at (7,6)
    coordinate (aux4) at (4,1.1)
    coordinate (aux5) at (7,1.3)
    coordinate (aux6) at (2,5.7)
    coordinate (aux7) at (5,5.1)
    coordinate (esp1) at (0.2,2.5)
    coordinate (esp2) at (1.5,1.5)
    coordinate (esp3) at (3,0.9)
    coordinate (esp4) at (5.5,1.4)
    coordinate (esp5) at (6,0.5)
    coordinate (esp6) at (6.75,2)
    coordinate (esp7) at (7.7,3)
    coordinate (esp8) at (5.5,4.5)
    coordinate (esp9) at (3.8,4.8)
    coordinate (esp10) at (1.5,4)
    ;
    \draw[line width=0.8pt,postaction={decorate,
        decoration={markings,
        mark=between positions 0 and 1 step 0.1 with
        {\coordinate%[label=\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number}]
         (p\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/decoration/mark info/sequence number});}}}]
    (esp1) to[out=-90,in=170]
    (esp2) to[out=-10,in=170]
    (esp3) to[out=-10,in=180]
    (esp4) to[out=0,in=180]
    (esp5) to[out=10,in=-150]
    (esp6) to[out=20,in=-90]
    (esp7) to[out=90,in=-60]
    (esp8) to[out=120,in=0]
    (esp9) to[out=180,in=0]
    (esp10) to[out=180,in=90]
    cycle;    
    \clip
    (esp1) to[out=-90,in=170]
    (esp2) to[out=-10,in=170]
    (esp3) to[out=-10,in=180]
    (esp4) to[out=0,in=180]
    (esp5) to[out=10,in=-150]
    (esp6) to[out=20,in=-90]
    (esp7) to[out=90,in=-60]
    (esp8) to[out=120,in=0]
    (esp9) to[out=180,in=0]
    (esp10) to[out=180,in=90]
    cycle;    
    \draw[red,thick,pattern=north east lines,pattern color=red] (p5|-p1) rectangle (p8|-p7);
    \draw[red,thick] (p1) -| (p3) (p10) |- (p1) (p9) |- (p1) (p8) |- (p1)
    (p8) |- (p7) (p4) |- (p1) (p2) |- (p6) (p9) |- (p8|-p7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]